# web3.py event listener functionality doesn't catch events

Tags: web3.py

I want is to listen to the event "IPFSHash" defined in a Solidity contract in a python module using web3.py (with blockchain created by ganache-cli, transactions triggered through Remix IDE also connected through Web3 Provider). I tried using this construct:

```
event_filter = my_contract.events.IpfsHash.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
while{True}: 
    event_filter.get_new_entries()
```

However, I don't get any new entries in the filter when triggering the event through Remix. I can however call the getHash function to confirm that the value of "hash" is changed in the contract and the event has been emitted (full code below).

Thanks!!!

Web3.py code:

```
import json
from web3.providers.rpc import HTTPProvider
from web3 import Web3
import time

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
contract_address = 
Web3.toChecksumAddress("0xa293277dcd6f2e98ba63583fb81ed72f7555c8ef")

with open('contract_abi.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as abi_file:
    contract_abi = json.loads(abi_file.read())

my_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)

event_filter = my_contract.events.IpfsHash.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')

poll_interval = 2

def handle_event(event):
    print("Event triggered")

while True:
   print("New entries: ", len(event_filter.get_new_entries()))
   for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
       handle_event(event)
   print("Get Hash:", contract.functions.getHash().call())
   time.sleep(poll_interval)
```

Solidity contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;
contract HashEventTest{
    bytes public hash;

    event IpfsHash(
        bytes ipfs_hash,
        address sender
     );

    function HashEventTest(bytes _hash) public {
        hash = _hash;
    }

    function setHash(bytes _hash) public {
        hash = _hash;
        emit IpfsHash(hash, msg.sender);
    }

    function getHash() public constant returns (bytes){
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had the same issue and reproted it. See [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/730#issuecomment-377790953) the discussion. No solution yet.

However, the old method works fine, for instance:

```
myfilter = mycontract.eventFilter('EventName', {'fromBlock': 0,'toBlock': 'latest'});
eventlist = myfilter.get_all_entries()
```

This will work.

hope this helps